# Agregar una imagen a PDF Visual studio 2019 iTextSharp.text.pdf

Tags: itextsharp

Sucede que no logro anexar un logo a mi reporte, muestro parte del código para solicitar su grandiosa ayuda de que estoy haciendo mal.

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.IO
    Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Imports System
    Imports System.Windows.Forms
    Imports System.Drawing
    Imports System.Drawing.Printing


Dim IMAGEN As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:\logfin_1.jpg")
        IMAGEN.ScaleToFit(100, 100)
```

y así lo llamo ..

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox1.IMAGEN, 380, 335, 75, 75)
```

y aquí el error del compilador

```
Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.NullReferenceException' en Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Variable de objeto o de bloque With no establecida.
```

Que estoy haciendo mal??

Comment: ¿PictureBox1 donde lo declaraste?

Comment: Si, ya lo resolví y no estaba declarado mi PB1, gracias y disculpa.